# How to obtain first item from first vector in a set of vectors?

Tags: vector, clojure

I have a set containing vectors, e.g. `#{[1 2 3]}`, and I want to get the first element of the first member of the set. Is there a more idiomatic way to do this than `(first (first set))` ?

Comment: [`ffirst`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/ffirst). Note there's no guaranteed ordering in a set as mentioned below.

Answer (score 6):

The default clojure set is unordered, so calling `first` on them doesn't really make sense (unless you know for sure it's a set of 1 element). It does make sense if it's a sorted set. What you have done would be the idiomatic way to get the first element of the first of any collection. Another option from core is `ffirst`. I would say that's slightly less idiomatic in the community but still fine.

Comment: Actually, there are both non-sorted (default) and sorted sets, you can create the latter with `(sorted-set)`, and there's also the option to pass a custom comparator to be used to determine element order, see https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/sorted-set

Comment: Oh! I forgot there was a sorted-set, I only remembered sorted-map. Updated answer thank you.